# jQuery Mobile: Is there a way to do some js before the first page shows up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, event-handling

I´m developing an app with jQuery Mobile and Phonegap where I need to check a variable before the first page shows up. It´s only 3 lines of code, where I check if a variable is true or false. If it´s true the user gets redirected to another page with mobile.changePage().

So is there a way to check this variable before the user gets to see the first page. (Must be executed between splashscreen disappears and first page shows up. 
Thx for your help

Comment: You need to listen to `pagebeforechange`. http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforechange/

Comment: @Omar correct answer. Thank you! if you post it as an answer i´ll check it as correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen to [`pagebeforechange`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforechange/) event and not [`pagebeforeshow`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforeshow/). Because the first one fires before transition triggers and *most importantly* before updating browser's history.

- [**pagebeforechange**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforechange/): Triggered twice during the page change cyle: First prior to any page loading or transition and next after page loading completes successfully, but before the browser history has been modified by the navigation process.
- [**pagebeforeshow**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforeshow/): Triggered on the "toPage" we are transitioning to, before the actual transition animation is kicked off.

Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19522643/1771795

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/YaWpX/)**

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at JQM's `pagebeforeshow` event. Documentation is [here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforeshow/).

Comment: `pagebeforeshow` will result in showing the target page before redirecting.

Comment: @Omar so if you redirect before a page is shown it will still show the base page before the redirected page? I am going to have to test this later as that doesn't make sense. Not trying to be argumentative, truly trying to understand and help at the same time.

Comment: Fork this fiddle and use `pagebeforeshow`. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/YaWpX/ more details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520101/stop-showing-page/19522643#19522643

Comment: thx for reply. then pagebeforechange is the right event for me. But is this event fireing before the first page (index.html) shows up?

Comment: @Omar, took a look and you are right. My solution was based on a multipage site and using window.location to change page. I keep forgetting that the typical JQM site is a single page with multiple `<div data-role="page">` elements.

Comment: @m1crdy yes, it fires before. like in this demo, it goes directly to page3 before showing the first page http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Ea8Ya/

Comment: @Dom multi-page and single-page are the same as jQM loads pages via Ajax.