# Hide and remove jQuery mobile login page after login

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'v a site with jQuery Mobile multi page layout.

After AJAX login from `#Login` page user redirects to `#CustomerDashboard` or `#AdminDashboard` despending on the user type.

`$.mobile.changePage("#CustomerDashboard", { changeHash: true });`

My issue is that when user press back button the `#Login` page will be again displayed, and user can again login.

How can I prevent this?

if I removed the Login page using `$("#Login").remove();` back button still shows the login page renderd!

`#Login` page cannot be removed fully because when user signs out, i need to show the login form again. This can be prevented by saving the `Login` page HTML and injecting back to DOM after signout.

But even though Login page is removed it remains in the browser history.

if I detect an active session exists on login page and redirects the user back to dashboard, user will not be never reach the page/site that he visited before coming to my site

Comment: hide the Login id using jquery

Comment: When user clicks back, he will see the login page. However if you want to handle the above case, I suggest you use session.

Comment: You need to remove login page from `$.mobile.urlHistory.stack`. Try this after moving from login page. `$.mobile.urlHistory.stack.splice(0,1)`. Where `0` is the index of `login` page history inside history array. This is in case `login` page is the first page to be shown when you startup jQM framework.

Comment: or use this method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520101/stop-showing-page/19522643#19522643

Comment: `$.mobile.urlHistory` is not defined for jQM 1.4.0. Instead `$.mobile.History` is there but firebug shows it as constructor function in red color

Comment: true, this was used in earlier versions. It's changed in 1.4, i'll look it up. but anyway, you can utilize `pagebeforechange` as in the answer above.

Comment: it's `$.mobile.navigate.history.stack` for jQM => 1.4

Answer (score 0):

Rudimentary way, simply force the user off the page if they try to return to it:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#login-page', function() {
    if(login === 1) {//login condition
        $.mobile.changePage("#dashboard-page");
    }
});
```